# Can't seem to get this MouseMotionListener to work [Java]

Tags: java, graphics, mousemotionlistener

so I have an issue with getting my MouseMotionListener to work. This is for a game where I want my image to rotate towards the direction of my mouse.
The problem is that the program won't actually get the mouseX and mouseY and it also won't even detect that the mouse is moving. I think the issue is that I do not know how to "addMouseMotionListener" correctly. I tried looking it up, but I can't seem to find an example that I understand to where I can put it in my code.

First off, here is my class for the listener.

```
public class MouseListener implements MouseMotionListener{

    public static int mouseX, mouseY;

    public void tick() {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX = e.getX();
        mouseY = e.getY();
        System.out.println("moved");
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the rotating image I want:

```
private int mouseY = MouseListener.mouseY;
private int mouseX = MouseListener.mouseX;
private float angle = (float)(Math.atan2(y - mouseY, x - mouseX));

@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {

    AffineTransform tran = new AffineTransform();
    tran.rotate(0, 0, 0);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.rotate(angle, x, y);
    g2d.fillRect(x, y, 64, 64);
    g2d.setTransform(tran);

}
```

And finally here is where I attempt to add the listener:

```
public void init() {
    inputManager = new InputManager();

    display.createDisplay();
    display.getFrame().addKeyListener(inputManager);
    display.getFrame().addMouseMotionListener(mouseListener);

    Assets.init();

    gameState = new GameState(this);
    State.setState(gameState);
}
```

And just in case, you should know I'm using a canvas for rendering my images.

Tell me if there is any more code you'd like to see.

EDIT: Here is the new code for my player class:

```
@Override
public void tick() {
    input();

    mouseY = game.getMouseListener().mouseY;
    mouseX = game.getMouseListener().mouseX;
    angle = (float)(Math.atan2(y - mouseY, x - mouseX) - Math.PI / 2);
}

@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {

    AffineTransform tran = new AffineTransform();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.rotate(angle, x, y);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite, x, y, size, size, null);
    g2d.setTransform(tran);
}
```

Comment: display.getFrame().addMouseListener(mouseListener);

Add this line too.

Comment: @CRazyProgrammer it is in there, seen in the last shown bit of code. EDIT: oh i see

Comment: I could be wrong, but let me know if it's working now..

Comment: @CRazyProgrammer That did not seem to do anything.

Comment: There are a potential series of problems, but there's not enough context to be 100% sure, I suspect that the frame's root pane or consent pane may be absorbing the mouse events before your frame can be notified. Instead try using display.getFrame().getContentPane() and add the listener to it, if that fails, you need to provide a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: Static is not a cross communications mechanism, the listener should update some kind of model on which the engine uses to make decisions

Comment: Alright so I added the mouse listener directly to the canvas I'm using but it only updates once, which is when I launch the program.

Comment: Based on your limited example, you never update the angle variable, this should be done once every cycle of your main loop, before you render anything

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay I tried to put my angle and mouse x/y variables into the tick method for my player class but it did not seem to do much, suprisingly. I expected that to be a fix. I'll post the new code.

Comment: @JustinRobinson Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer I fixed it. Ended up being problems with the objects I was assigning to my MouseListener class. Thanks.